# converting dates in R is changing to future dates, not past

Tags: r, date

I use this:

```
want=as.Date(date, '%d-%b-%y')
```

to convert dates like this: `1-JAN-52`

Instead of returning '1952-01-01' I am getting '2052-01-01'. Any advice?

Comment: ```as.Date``` uses ```strptime``` for formatting. The documentation says that %y assumes that the century is 20 for 00 to 68 and 19 for 69 to 99 (this is the 2018 POSIX standard). So, keeping this in mind, you need to build around this with your context in mind. E.g. if it's always the 19th century you're dealing with, consider using the century explicitly and using the %Y format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to modern computers, all shaped after the early Unix systems of the 1970s.  The start of time, so to speak, is the epoch, aka 1 Jan 1970.

Your problem here, in a nutshell, is the *inferior* input data. You only supply two years *and by a widely followed convention*, values less than 70 are taken for the next century.  It's all about the epoch.

So you have two choices. You could preprend '19' to the year part and parse via `%Y`, or you could just take the year value out of the date and reduce it by 100 if need be.

Some example code for the second (and IMHO better) option, makeing 1970 the cutoff date:

```
> datestr <- "1-Jan-52" 
> d <- as.Date(datestr, '%d-%b-%y')   
> 
> d 
[1] "2052-01-01" 
>                
> if (as.integer(strftime(d, "%Y")) >= 1970) { 
+   dp <- as.POSIXlt(d)
+   dp$year <- dp$year - 100
+   d <- as.Date(dp) 
+}     
> d    
[1] "1952-01-01"
>
```

You need to go via `POSIXlt` to get the components easily.

Comment: For dates with year between 70 and 99, e.g. ```datestr <- "1-Jan-72"```, your solution returns dates in the 18th century (```"1872-01-01"``)`.

Comment: In fact, the new range is 1870-1969.

Comment: The cut-off date can be selected as desired. I didn't claim that the solution above is exhaustive -- it was an illustration for his case at hand.  Refinements are surely possibe. But the key is for proper precision four-digit years should be used.